# Spawning a new thread for each object load

Tags: multithreading

I have a system which runs multiple service (long lived) and worker (short lived) threads. They all share a state which contains objects. Any thread can request an object an any time, through a singleton-of-sorts class called `ObjectManager`. If the object is not available it needs to be loaded.

Here's some pseudo-code of how object loading looks now:

```cpp
class ObjectManager {
    getLoadinData(path) {
        if (hasLoadingDataFor(path))
            return whatWeHave()
        else {
            loadingData = createNewLoadingData();
            loadingData.path = path;
            pushLoadingTaskToLoadingThread(loadingData);
            return loadingData;
        }
    }

    // loads object and blocks until it's loaded
    loadObjectSync(path) {
        loadingData = getLoadinData(path);
        waitFor(loadingData.conditionVar);
        return loadingData.loadedObject;
    }

    // initiates a load and calls a callback when done
    loadObjectAsync(path, callback) {
        loadingData = getLoadinData(path);
        loadingData.callbacks.add(callback);
    }

    // dedicated loading thread
    loadingThread() {
        while (running) {
            loadingData = waitForLoadingData();        
            object = readObjectFromDisk(loadingData.path);

            object.onLoaded(); // !!!!

            loadingData.object = object;
            // unblock cv waiters
            loadingData.conditionVar.notifyAll();
            // call callbacks
            loadingData.callbacks.callAll(object);
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem is the line `object.onLoaded`. I have no control over this function. Some objects might decide that they need other objects to be valid. So in their `onLoaded` method they might call `loadObjectSync`. Uh-oh! This (naturally) dead locks. It blocks the loading loop until the loading loop makes more iterations.

What I could do to solve this is leave the `onLoaded` call to the initiating threads. This will change `loadObjectSync` to something like:

```cpp
loadObjectSync(path) {
    loadingData = getLoadinData(path);
    waitFor(loadingData.conditionVar);
    if (loadingData.wasCreatedInThisThread()) {
        object.onLoaded();
        loadingData.onLoadedConditionVar.notifyAll();
        loadingData.callbacks.callAll(object);
    }
    else {
        // wait more
        waitFor(loadingData.onLoadedConditionVar);
    }                
    return loadingData.loadedObject;
}
```

... but then the problem is that if I have no calls for `loadSync` and only for `loadAsync` or simply the `loadAsync` call was the first to create the loading data, there will be no one to finalize the object. So to make this work, I have to introduce another thread finalizes objects whose loadingData was created by loadObjectAsync.

It seems that it would work. But I have a simpler idea! What if I change `getLoadingData` instead. What if it does this:

```cpp
getLoadinData(path) {
    if (hasLoadingDataFor(path))
        return whatWeHave()
    else {
        loadingData = createNewLoadingData();
        loadingData.path = path;
        ///
        thread = spawnLoadingThread(loadingData);
        thread.detach();
        ///
        return loadingData;
    }
}
```

Spawn a new thread for **every** object load. Thus there is no dead lock. Every loading thread can safely block until it's done. The rest of the code remains exactly as it is.

This means potentially tens (or why not thousands in certain edge cases) active threads, waiting on condition variables. I know that spawning threads has its overhead but I think it would be negligible compared to the cost of I/O from `readObjectFromDisk`

So my question is: Is this terrible? Can this somehow backfire?

The target platform is conventional desktop machines. But this software is supposed to run for a long time without stopping: weeks, maybe months.

Alternatively... even though I have an idea how to solve this if the thread-per-load turns out to be terrible, can this be solved in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting! This is a problem I have bumped into a couple of times, trying to add a synchronous interface to a fundamentally asynchronous operation (i.e. file load, or in my case, network write) that is performed by a service thread.

My own preference would be to not provide the synchronous interface.  Why? Because it keeps the code simpler in design & implementation and easier to reason about -- always important for multi-threading.

Benefits of sticking to single thread & async only is that you only have 1 service thread, so resource growth is not a concern, plus the user callbacks are always invoked on this same thread, which simplifies thread-safety concerns for users of `ObjectManager` (if you have multiple callback threads, every user callback must be thread safe, so it's an important choice to make).  However sticking to only an async interface does mean the user of `ObjectManager` has more work to do.

But if you do want to keep the synchronous interface, then another approach that I have taken could work for you.  You stick to a single service thread but inside the implementation of `loadObjectSync` you check the thread-ID to determine if the invoker is the service thread  or any-other thread.  If it is any-other thread you queue the request and safely block.  But if it is the service thread, you can immediately load the object, say by calling a new function `loadObjectImpl`.  You will need to grab the thread-ID of the service thread during initialization and store it within the `ObjectManager` instance, and use that for thread identification.  And you will need a new function which is basically just the internal scope of the `loadingThread` function -- i.e. a new function called something like `loadObjectImpl`.

Comment: I need the synchronous interface. Without it workers will become much more complicated. You couldn't spawn a simple worker like `getX(); useX();` It would put too much responsibility on worker writers, which is precisely what I'm trying to solve.

As for the immediate load. I had thought about it, but this means loading objects multiple times. Unpleasant. If thread A requests object "Bag" which in turn requests object "Milk" (to be loaded immediately), and in the mean time thread B requests just "Milk" they won't be able to wait on the same condition var. And "Milk" would be loaded twice.

Comment: actually that last part is not necessarily true... hmmm let me get back to you on that. I'll make an experiment

Comment: Yeah, regarding loading objects multiple times.  This requires a mutex protected map<name, Object> store, which was not included in your snippet.     I think the service thread would have to lock the mutex just prior to loading an object and hodholding it until the full recursive set of objects had been loaded.  So while service thread is loading "Milk", it holds lock, which prevents thread B from progressing (since it too needs to acquire lock).    You might hit deadlock problem if service thread attempts to acquire same lock twice ... but ways around that.

Comment: Ok, this does work. The main problem is that the call stack can get pretty deep, but I guess I can live with that.

It would be nice to have an answer to the thread-per-load question though. Is it a terrible idea?